# Shiny: Observe() on reactiveValues()

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have created a Shiny App around a `reactiveValues()` variable dump. Using `observeEvent()` observing a simple action button I fill these values using custom functions. In addition, I am trying to observe the one of them (`Query$A`) in order to update another input element.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    Query <- reactiveValues(A=NULL, B=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$SomeActionButton,{
        Query$A <- SomeCustomFunction(url)
        Query$B <- SomeOtherFunction(sqlScheme)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "QueryScheme", choices =  Query$B)
    })

    observe(Query$A, {
        QueryNames <- sort(names(Query$B))
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "SortedSchemes", choices = QueryNames)
    })

})
```

This produces, probably not to the surprise of some more senior Shiny developers,

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

I think I understand why this does not work, the question would then be what to do? I found that `isolate()` works outside of reactive context but I am not sure if this is the proper way to implement such a logic.

I am eventually trying to have several inputs based of observers that do not require actions buttons. Is this possible or do I misuse the concept here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Query$A` from your observe statement. The observe statement will determine when to run based on what dependencies are contained within it.

Minimal working example using your app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    selectInput("QueryScheme",            "QueryScheme",           choices = sample(1:10, 3)),
    selectInput("SortedSchemes",          "SortedSchemes",         choices = sample(1:10, 3)),
    actionButton("SomeActionButton",      "SomeActionButton"),
    actionButton("UnrelatedActionButton", "UnrelatedActionButton")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    #Reactive Values
    Query <- reactiveValues(A = NULL, B = NULL)
    
    #Observe Some Action Button (runs once when button pressed)
    observeEvent(input$SomeActionButton,{
        Query$A <- sample(1:10, 3)
        Query$B <- sample(1:10, 3)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "QueryScheme", choices =  Query$B)
    })

    #Observe reactive value Query$B (runs once when Query$B changes)
    observe({
        showNotification("Query$B has changed, running Observe Function")
        QueryNames <- sort(Query$B)
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "SortedSchemes", choices = QueryNames)
    })
    
    #Observe Unrelated Action Button (runs once when button pressed) note that it won't trigger the above observe function
    observeEvent(input$UnrelatedActionButton,{
        showNotification("UnrelatedActionButton Pressed")
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to use `observeEvent` rather than `observe`.